# Set-Reset Latches and D Latches

Tags: latch

I am trying really hard to understand the way SR Latches and D Latches work.I've realised that in a SR Latch we got a current state let's say Q(t) and Q'(t) and we want to predict the next state let's say Q(t+1) and Q'(t+1) by changing the inputs R and S.My question is : Do Q(t) and Q'(t) work as inputs as well? I've studied the NAND and NOR implementations for SR Latches and the NAND implementation for D Latches.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Q and Q' are outputs. As you can see in this NAND-based vircuit they each have an output connected to them, so you cannot connect another output to either one.

[image]

You have the two inputs /S and /R to influence the Q(t)/Q'(t).

PS you mention both SR and D latches, but I see no question about D latches. But fro a D latch the outputs are the same (Q and Q'), and you can't connect any other output to them.

Comment: If Q(t) and Q'(t) are outputs then what are Q(t+1) and Q'(t+1)? I mean you want to predict the next state which is Q(t+1) but as i see it the outputs Q(t) and Q'(t) seem to be the Q(t+1) and Q'(t+1) that you want to predict.I just need a clarification on this one.

Comment: The t suffix denotes the time: Q(t) is the previous Q level, Q(t+1) is the next Q level.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a SR latch the outputs Q and Q' are fed back to inputs of each of the NAND/NOR gates. Seen from outside Q and Q' act only as outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is better representation of a good latch, it requires both and enable signal with a set or reset signal to protect it from being overwritten by the bus.

A latch with set,reset and enable bits (AKA bus protection)

[image: latch schematic]